Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.User: Property or indexer 'ControllerBase.User' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
I am attempting to fix code after updating framwork from .net 4.8 framework to .net8. I am dealing with an issue in my code here :


controller.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("test"), new[] { Roles.VirtualUser });



Where controller.User is apparently readonly. This is what User looks like in the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.mvc:


 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for user associated with the executing action.
 /// </summary>
 public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User!;



I am not sure what is causing this code to break. I have read though the similar posts but I dont believe any of them have the exact problem. I have seen I could need a setter method, but dont believe I can edit the library code. Any suggestions / tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I don't see this being specific to .Net8, as Controller.User was readonly in Asp.Net MVC 5 too (see e.g. system.web.mvc.controller.user. Maybe this was always broken?

You can use one from the ControllerBase.HttpContext. For example in the controller's action:
HttpContext.User = 
   new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("test"), new[] { Roles.VirtualUser });


Thank you!! This is what I was looking for. Do you know how I could get rid of this error that it is causing me? My methods arent static, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this;
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.User'

@Maya TBH - don't know. The shown code was tested with controller action and worked fine. Note that HttpContext is not static anymore, it is ControllerBase's property.

Okay thanks! As soon as I can figure out whats making my test a static context / understand whats going on I can accept your answer, thanks for your help

@Maya it seems that it should be something like controller.HttpContext.User in your case.
